# Simple calculator- android application

Tags: android

I am trying to make simple calculator with buttons and one text view on android
I wanna every button that I pressed appear in text view without replacing the previous text 
for example 44+3 = 47 
but there is some problem 
how can i take the value of the first number that existed before the operation and put it in the first variable and take the second number that existed after the operation and put it in second variable ?!!

Comment: Check [this](http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.in/2012/11/simple-calculator-in-android.html) out. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Search for **Postfix-Infix** conversion.

It is used to make calculations. It basically uses 2 **Stacks**. You store operators in one stack and numbers in another stack, or **String Buffer**.

If your goal is to calculate summation of two numbers you can do this easily parsing string. But if you wanna put multiplication, division etc. you have to use **Postfix** notation. Because multiplication and division has priority over summation and subtraction.